# Правильно ли я понимаю значимость XML в разработке веб приложений на Java?

Tags: java, xml

Добрый день. Я прохожу сейчас работу с XML в Java но там как вы понимайте только теория и задания. Вот у меня назрел вопрос для чего он нужен в веб разработке? Я достаточно много почитал о применении но там не все так одназначно сказано.

Как я понимаю если я разрабатываю веб приложение допустим с помощью JSP то когда на стороне клиета я отправляю данные я их структурирую с помощью JS в XML, отправляю на сервер, там их вытаскиваю через парсинг, обрабатываю их. Так же и наобарот я на стороне сервера достаю данные из СУБД, например, пакую их в XML и отправляю уже в веб клиент. Правильно ли я понял? Так же удобства хранения в XML разного вида настроек и конфигураций я не оспариваю.

Если вас не затруднит приведите пару примеров ещё что бы понять значимость XML.

Comment: А примеры "незначимости XML" не нужны?

Comment: Минусуют-то за что?

Comment: а http://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds можно считать примером "значимости"? Или этого не достаточно и вы хотите услышать почему не, например, json?

Answer (score 1):

Существует довольно распростарненное мнение, что XML устарел, как формат для передачи данных от клиента к серверу. Он громоздкий, менее читабельный, чем JSON, у него мудреные парсеры. Я бы использовал JSON, мне он кажется практичнее гораздо. XML при этом используется в конфигурациях различных фрейморков типа Spring, Hibernate, Log4j2 например, при этом многие позволяют делать конфигурацию с помощью аннотаций, вместо XML, что гораздо компактнее и современнее. Что там изучать, я особо не представляю, это ведь просто формат представления информации.

Если делаете новый проект, то рекомендую минимизировать работу с XML в сторону более современных тенденций (например, описанные выше JSON, аннотации и др.)

Comment: Ну я пока хочу стать джуном по спецификации JEE (точнее львиную часть от неё). Посмотрел на вид JSON, выглядит и правда не так объемно как XML

Comment: _Что там изучать, я особо не представляю_ - гм, я не согласен с этим. Если брать в целом, то XML - чудовищно сложная технология, на полное освоение которой нужны месяцы, если не годы. В частности, чего стоит расширение Infoset после валидации по XmlSchema: в данные могут быть добавлены (а могут и нет) значения по умолчанию. Лично мне приходилось сталкиваться с серьёзными проблемами из-за этого. Однако, если использовать XML просто для передачи автоматически сериализованных данных, то действительно всё просто.

Answer (score 0):

Да не нужен он. Все давно на json переходят.

Хотя у джавы всё на xml - вероятно там он живёт дольше чем надо, даже в других местах...

Comment: А как же всякие документы разных Officов? Они тоже все дружно встали и перешли на json?

Comment: @Sergey, но ведь вопрос-то про web-разработку, а не про офисные форматы.

Comment: а wsdl сервисы? там ещё и валидация по xsd dtd схемам. схемы для json-а уже утвердили?

Comment: @Sergey, rest api?

Comment: rest api не диктует особых условий в какой системе кодирования будет гонятся информация. json, xml, html, csv, dbf, text - всё равно если клиент и сервер договорятся

Comment: @Sergey, именно :)